# crossfilter filtering with blanks

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm using crossfilter and dc to render charts of subject-related observations.

Each observation gets treated as a dimension. However, not all rows will have values for all dimensions as some dimensions have data that is repeated over time. For example, `Column A` has four values over four rows, but `Column B` has only one value so the other three rows it will be `0` / `""` / `blank`.

Now if I filter on `Column B` for rows with a certain range / value, then automatically I lose all other rows for `Column A` and if I wanted to filter on `Column A` AFTER filter on `Column B` then I'm only filtering out of the one common row that has values for both.

This may sound as a logical behaviour, but it's not true to the data, because if I wanted to filter subjects (i.e.) rows that have a certain range for `Column A` AND a certain range for `Column B` that results in a wrong result, because of the blank values which are not missing they are just there because it's a table and all columns are expected to have values for all rows.

Is there a way to be able to filter on `Column B` without that excluding values from `Column B` only because they're blank?

I'm sorry that took that much text to explain!

UPDATE

An example: observation data is collected for patients, let's say 'weight' and 'blood pressure'. For one subject there might be two weight readings, but four blood pressure readings. When I try to create the data structure for crossfilter, I create two columns one for weight and another for blood pressure. I want to display to the user two bar charts showing the distrubtion of values in each pbservation across all subjects. The user should be able to filter subjects with a weight range AND a blood pressure range. Because two of the rows for a subject will not have values for blood pressure, filtering on weight will filter out subjects(i.e. rows) that might be in the range for the blood pressure filter, but did not have a value for weight so they were wrongly excluded

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it with arrays so now instead of my data structured in a flat table-like structure:

```
{subjectId: "subject-101", study: "CRC305A", A: "24", B: "79"}
{subjectId: "subject-101", study: "CRC305A", A: "", B: "74"}
{subjectId: "subject-101", study: "CRC305A", A: "", B: "83"}
{subjectId: "subject-101", study: "CRC305A", A: "", B: "74"}
{subjectId: "subject-101", study: "CRC305A", A: "", B: "72"}
{subjectId: "subject-101", study: "CRC305A", A: "", B: "82"}
{subjectId: "subject-101", study: "CRC305A", A: "", B: "74"}
{subjectId: "subject-101", study: "CRC305A", A: "", B: "79"}
{subjectId: "subject-101", study: "CRC305A", A: "", B: "76"}
{subjectId: "subject-101", study: "CRC305A", A: "", B: "72"}
```

it's structured as below to allow variability in values from one column to another

```
{subjectId: “subject-101", 
 A:[“24”],
 B:[“79", "74", "83", "74", "72", "82", "74", "79", "76", "72", "79", "76", "77", "72", "83", "69", "72”]
}
```

And the filtering magically works!

Have one problem still related to the behaviour of **dimension.top** and **dimension.bottom** with respect to arrays. I'll post that in another question

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 0):

If the values are logically there, you should probably propagate them to the next rows before sticking them in crossfilter. Crossfilter doesn't have any concept of row order or defaulted values.

If I understand your question correctly, I'd do something like

```
var lastA, lastB, lastC;
data.forEach(function(d) {
  if(d.A)
    lastA = d.A:
  else
    d.A = lastA;
  if(d.B)
    lastB = d.B;
  else
    d.B = lastB
  // ...
});
var cf = crossfilter(data);
```

Trying to create sort of "wildcard values" like you suggest in your question, might be possible but you'd definitely have to change at least the [filter handler](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filterHandler__anchor) for every chart, because they expect to be dealing with discrete values.

Comment: Thanks but this way I'll be introducing 'made up' data and I can't generalise that rule of filling in data as it gets tricky if for one column there are TWO row values, but for column B there are FOUR row values for the same time points! Now which values for column A would I use to populate the remaining two rows. I'd be introducing fake data and this would be very sensitive to my application

Comment: When you said "over time", I thought you meant that once a measurement is taken, it will hold until it is measured again in a later row. Okay, I guess you would need wildcards, a special value which matches any other value.

Comment: I'll try using wildcards then. I was thinking of using arrays, but not sure if a bar chart can work of a crossfilter array with numeric values? So far I've only seen row charts created from array of strings. Could you please advise? ..thanks

Comment: Hmm, array / tag dimension is similar but I'm not sure how you'd apply it. I am thinking you need a special sentinel value and also a special filter function that detects it. Let me see if I can hack something up, don't think I've seen this requirement before.

Comment: I'll update the question with a real example to make it clearer

Comment: Sounds like you could use a filter function that never filters out blank values?

Comment: Thanks @EthanJewett, yes that is probably more clear than "wildcard value". I'll try to hack up an example later today.